pressables inputs and all touchable elements not working after animating transform properties of parent view in sdk52
i have custome modals, popups ...ui-elements , after updating my expo project to sdk52 the touch event are not firing and not behaving as expected in animated views , this is my modal code i cant get it to work
const startPosition = useSharedValue<number>(0);
const translate = useSharedValue(0);

const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(
    () => ({
        transform: [
            position === 'bottom'
                ? { translateY: translate.value }
                : { translateX: translate.value },
        ],
        opacity: translate.value === startPosition.value ? 0 : 1,
    }),
    []
);

const controls = useRef({
    show: (event: LayoutChangeEvent) => {
        if (translate.value === 0) return;
        const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
        const size =
            position === 'bottom'
                ? layout.height
                : position === 'start-x'
                ? layout.width
                : -layout.width;
        translate.value = size;
        startPosition.value = size;

        translate.value = withSpring(0, {
            mass: 0.3,
            damping: 20,
            stiffness: 100,
        });
    },
    hide: () => {
        translate.value = withSpring(startPosition.value, {
            mass: 0.3,
            damping: 20,
            stiffness: 100,
        });
    },
}).current;

i tried changing its margintTop animation completion, that worked in ios and made everything active but in android no! ,  "expo": "^52.0.23","react-native": "0.76.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.20.2", "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
